# Creating an Indexer in Azure Search: Schema identifying Edm.Complex types in one subscription but not another

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azureportal

I’m seeing some inconsistent behavior between two different subscriptions when trying to create an Indexer for an Azure Search service through the Azure Portal.

I was able to successfully build the indexers in our test/ppe subscription (Microsoft) using a Cosmos DB collection as a source and the data was matched 1:1 using Edm.ComplexType and Collection(Edm.ComplexType):

[Complex Types showing up in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiMtq.png)

After I verified things were working as expected, I moved to our prod subscription (AME.GBL) to do the same; however, this ability to add/edit complex types seems to be missing:

[Complex Types not showing up in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOkfX.png)

Is there a reason why this ability to add complex types is available in one of our subscriptions but not the other?

Is there a feature gate in place for this ability to add/edit Complex types for an index and if there is, would it be possibly to manually override it for a given subscription ID?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried calling the API to see what it returns for the indexes I already created and I got this message:  `"This index was created with a newer version of the Azure Search API and uses features exclusive to that version. Please use the latest API version (2019-05-06) to manage this index."`  Looks like there is a new API version which our test/ppe subscription had access to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bradley - You are correct that in this case the Complex Type detection feature via the portal 'Import Data' workflow is currently only available via the internal Microsoft portal experience.  However, this feature will be deployed publicly world-wide very soon and we are targeting 5/1/2019 for global availability via the portal.  If you need to create this index with Complex Types beforehand you can use the API to set the index schema with the complex types directly.

Comment: Thanks Brian - this feature is really cool and I can't wait to share it with my team.